# MATLAB regexprep with parentheses

Tags: regex, matlab, regexp-replace

Given a cell array of strings:

```
CellArray={'(first)';'second';'x(third)';'four)'; '(...)'};
```

I would like the following result:

```
newCellArray={'first';'second';'x(third)';'four)';'...'};
```

i.e. I would like to remove the parentheses only if they are at the start and end of the word...

I would like to use something like:

```
newCellArray = regexprep(CellArray,expression,replace);
```

But sadly, I did not succeed despite many attempts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [beginning and end anchors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42983) with a [token capture](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#f0-42884) and a [back-replace](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html#inputarg_replace):

```
>> expr = '^\((.+)\)$';
>> CellArray = {'(first)';'second';'x(third)';'four)'; '(...)'};
>> newCellArray = regexprep(CellArray,expr,'$1')

newCellArray = 

    'first'
    'second'
    'x(third)'
    'four)'
    '...'
```